# With which subclasses of EventObject is CommandStackListener.commandStackChanged(EventObject) invoked in GEF?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef

I added a `CommandStackListener` to my `GraphicalEditor`'s command stack:

```
getCommandStack().addCommandStackListener(new CommandStackListener() {
    public void commandStackChanged(EventObject event) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But I guess if I want to get information from the `event` parameter, I need to do a cast first.  However, I don't know which subclasses of `EventObject` are used here.  I am trying to detect the case where the command stack was changed or saved.

Answer (score 0):

GEF's default implementation of command stack only passes EventObject to command stack listeners which is really one type - just a wrapper for the CommandStack object. Subclasses of the CommandStack can potentially pass a subclass of EventObject which then may be parsed.
However, perhaps what you're looking for is really the CommandStackEventListener which gets the CommandStackEvent object that might be more useful in your case.
BTW, what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I had a class that needed to perform some action when `CommandStack.markSaveLocation()` was called in my `GraphicalEditor`. However, the editor isn't aware of that class, so I had to use a listener. The `CommandStackEventListener` does provide more information indeed, but it does not seem to regocnize this save event, so it does not work for me. Anyway, I found a better way to solve my problem without the need of using the listener.